# Getting values using GetRelation

Tags: content-hub-scripting

I'm brand new to Sitecore, just doing acceptance testing.  Needing to write a script that takes the value selected for one field (a taxonomy) and then populates two other fields (both taxonomies).

How do I get the displayed value for an `IChildToManParentsRelation`? Update: I was able to get the ID of first relation "IndustryLine".  That being said, next step is to get the displayed value using that ID.  Beating my head against the wall trying to figure it out.

```
var industryrel = asset.GetRelation("IndustryLineToAsset");
var industrylist = industryrel.GetIds();
var industrycount = industrylist.Count;
var industryID = industrylist[0];
```

What comes next to pull the displayed value for the relation based on the industryID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer as simple as it should be:
Query the entity by it's Id with your MClient instance.

```
IEntity industryLine = await MClient.Entities.GetAsync(industryID);
```

More information you can find in Web SDK [documentation](https://docs.stylelabs.com/contenthub/4.1.x/content/integrations/sdk-common-documentation/clients/entities-client.html)